# Cable company moving off of analog, will my HTPC still work?

Tags: htpc

I have an old plan with my cable company, we receive their "Basic TV" package that has analog channels plus the unencrypted local network HD channels (NBC, CBS, etc.). We have an HTPC I built a while back that has a [Hauppauge WinTV-HVR-2250 Media Center Kit Dual TV Tuner](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815116036), which supports the following standards:

- ATSC
- ClearQAM
- NTSC

The cable company called and offered a good rate for digital TV, but it would require getting a cable box. My question is, would our HTPC still work with the digital TV setup? (I asked the guy on from the cable company on the phone, but he was a salesman and not a technical guy, so he wasn't very helpful.)

Right now the coax cable comes in from the wall, into the HTPC, then an HDMI cable to the TV. My hope is that with the cable box I would be able to have the coax cable coming in from the wall go into the cable box, then from there into the HTPC, then the HDMI to the TV.

Thanks

Comment: The number of channels your HTPC will receive depends on which channels continue to be transmitted without encryption.  Some cable companies are encrypting all channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tuner won't be able to "tune" the digital signal offered by the cable company, so you'll need to let the digital set-top box they provide do that, and then pipe it's output into the HTPC as a line-in.

Once you set it up like this you won't be able to tune the signal with your tuner anymore, so you won't be able to change channels directly with the HTPC.  To do that, you'll need an [IR Blaster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_blaster) to control the set-top box's channels (etc.) from the HTPC.

If you actually bought the [WinTV-HVR-2250 *Media Center Kit* version](http://www.hauppauge.com/site/products/data_hvr2250.html) of that card (and not just the stand-alone card version), then it should have included at least one IR Blaster in the kit.

Comment: I did buy the kit and it did come with an IR Blaster... the question is whether I still have it and can find it! :-)

Comment: Well some good news is that [Hauppauge's 3 metre IR blaster](http://store.hauppauge.com/accessories2.asp?product=blaster) is only like $7. :)

Comment: You will still be able to use the card for over-the-air broadcasts, FWIW

Comment: @Keltari - Which are all digital not analog so you sure about that?

Comment: @techie007 -- His tuner has a clearQAM demodulator, so your statement about *"can only do over-the-air digital"* is inaccurate.  The OP clearly stated that local HD channels were being received, which would be QAM.

Comment: One further question: my current HTPC can now record two shows at once or record one while watching another, but I presume that would not be possible if I connect the HTPC to the line out from the cable box. I wager I'd only get a single channel, whatever channel the cable box was tuned to, no?

Comment: @sawdust Fair enough -- removed.

Comment: @Ramhound Digital broadcasts are in ATSC, which has card supports

Comment: @ScottMitchell You are right when saying that you will now be able to receive a single show at a time from your cable box when connected to the line out. However if your TV card can support different inputs for its tuners you could use OTA DTV with the second one by connecting it to an antenna.

Comment: @techie007 -- Your answer still assumes that all channels will be encrypted (although your assertion *"won't be able to "tune" the digital signal"* seems to have been based on an analog-only tuner misconception).  The OP has not confirmed whether that is actually true or not.  If there are still unencrypted QAM channels, then the HTPC's tuner is still usable.

Comment: @Sawdust Some assumptions have to be made based on the info given.  Personally, I've not run into a cable company that DOESN'T encrypt their digital channels.  By all means, since you seem to have an interest, if you think you have a better answer, or can improve mine, more power to you.  It'll only help I'm sure. :)